# Customize Rating Bar with different colour in android

Tags: android

Can you tell me how to make a rating bar such that at each point the color of the filled star is changed.
i.e we have 5 circles color of one circle should be red, other should be green then blue, then orange then yellow
When one is selected the color of first circle should be red
when two is selected the color of first circle should be red and the color of second circle should be green
and so on

My Rating bar looks like this:

when empty:
gray gray gray gray gray

when filled:
red blue green yellow orange